# How do I setup Basic Auth for the Fetch API?

Tags: fetch, basic-authentication, fetch-api, rest

So I have a referer and Basic Auth that I need to send a Get Request, no body is needed. I am sending out the function like this, but I am getting a Failed to Fetch Error

```
fetch(myUrl, {
    method: 'GET', // or 'PUT'
    headers: {
        'Referer': refererUrl,
    },
    authorization: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(authUser + ":" + authPassword),
    }
})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log('Success:', data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`Referer` is one of the headers that cannot be set by a client, for security reasons:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name

Comment: Is there anyway I can fix this?

Comment: You could not use a browser to make the HTTP request.